# Google Web Font - Distorting

Tags: css, fonts

I used Google web fonts for my H1 text and the text looks very pixelated on my screen.

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Forum&v2' rel='stylesheet'    type='text/css'>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

    h1 {
    color:#544E4F;
    font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:210%;
    }

    </style>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After suffering the same problem for a long time, and after doing a lot of research about it, I finally did the following:

1. I found http://www.fontsquirrel.com
2. I downloaded the (pixellated) font I was using (Exo family)
3. I uploaded it to my site
4. I referenced it locally to avoid using Google Fonts (you can achieve this by downloading a @font-face Kit that is available at fontsquirrel.com also).

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK to me. However note that `h1` receives the style:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

in most browsers' default style sheets. Since you only have a normal-weight variant of the font available, the browser has to synthesise the bold weight automatically from the normal. There are various different methods of auto-bolding of varying levels of quality, but it's never going to look as good as a real designed bold. Maybe you are getting a poorly-synthesised font variant.

If you want to use Forum for headings I suggest adding the rule:

```
font-weight: normal;
```

which will allow the browser to use the regular, unmolested font. Alternatively if you really do want that bold, best choose a different font that does actually have a bold weight.

Another possibility is that you've got anti-aliasing turned off at a system level, and it's being overridden for your normal browser font but not for web fonts. If that's the problem then you could *try* to override for everything else using eg:

```
font-smooth: always;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

although it's questionable whether it's really a good idea to be ignoring the user's preferences, and also arguable whether it should be `subpixel-antialiased` instead for WebKit...

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm just throwing these out there, but..

My best guess is to use em rather than % for your font size. Such as, font-size:4.5em.

Maybe try using a div instead of h1, though I doubt that would do much of anything.

Comment: Neither of those worked. I did this text1 {
color:#544E4F;
font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
text-align:center;
margin: auto;
font-size:2.1em;
} and no luck, it wouldn't even get the google font with it.

Comment: also, it is doing the pixelation on google chrome, firefox seems to show it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
h1 {
text-shadow:0 0 1px transparent;
}
```